# How to fix blank line appending at end of query result

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm attempting to create clean and professional looking queries for a college project, but for some reason a blank row starting with an asterisk appears at the end regardless of what I do.

So far I've tried a bunch of suggestions found on different forums, including setting the RecordsetType to "snapshot", and importing the file from a cleaned excel sheet, but so far I have had no luck.

The code for most cases is a simple SQL query such as this:

```
SELECT Table1.[Client Number], Table1.[Client Name], Table1.[Amount Paid], Table1.[Current Due]
FROM Table1;
```

Is the solution in the properties of my table/query, or is it perhaps within the code itself? I am VERY new to access, so forgive me if the question seems naive.

It should look like this:

[image]

but instead it looks like this:

[image]

I do want to reiterate that this IS for homework, but the question really has more to do with me wanting the output to look nice. (Which of course my Professor wants as well).

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's not a "blank line". It's the way ms-access works: It's a "new" row, where you can enter data to add another row using the visual tool. There may be an option to turn it off, but you can't make it go away by changing the SQL.

Comment: @Bohemian Hey, thanks so much! My professor seemed to want them to go away, but everywhere I looked seems to have that present... It's strange that he would not treat that as a "feature" so to speak. I do believe that he uses the older version of Access now that I think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, it is not possible to disable the data entry row when viewing the results returned by an MS Access query.

However, if you were to create a Datasheet Form whose Record Source is set to your saved query, then you can remove the blank row by setting the **Allow Additions** property to **No** within the properties of the form:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense to me, and explains a whole lot. I appreciate it.

Comment: @NathanCronauer You're most welcome - if my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark the answer as the solution (and upvote if you feel appropriate) so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site. For information on how to do this, refer to [this section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) of the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).